# I have this weird 1px "margin" around my ad, what gives?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, xaml

It's a simple project, and I have not played around a lot with the standard code. But I still get this weird 1px margin around my ad... in this case adduplex.

I've tried to set the with to 480, margin to 0 and for the page properties designheight is 800 and width is 480 :-/

Does anyone know what I can test/do to correct it? I dont want this margin (blue horizontal line, right of the black with white upper and lower border).

As I mentioned the black with upper and lower border is my AdDuplex Control. The blue line should be white, but because my app somehow needed this margin its blue as my background

Image: [image]

Comment: and this margin is... where...? in that picture? the thin blue line? one of the black lines? that weird white vertical bit?

Comment: @Marc B its the blue one there. sorry for not pointing it out

Comment: Probably in their control template.  Not sure if WP supports what I'd do, but you can create a new template for the control, or spelunk down the visual tree using the VisualTreeHelper to find the immediate child of that pesky border and stick that into your UI.  This is coming from a WPF dev.

Comment: Will's right, you'd have to find your culprit in their control template or create your own. You'd be looking for a Border with a BorderThickness=1 (since you indicated the blue line) I would imagine. If this ? is still here later I'll dig it out and take a look for ya.

Comment: I just remembered, the BorderThickness Dependency Property is likely Template bound anyway. Have you tried just adding BorderThickness="0" inline with the tag?